# List of control sequences in \033[ (for urxvt keysym)

Tags: ascii, keyboard-shortcuts, urxvt

I am trying to remap cursor moves and such in my terminal, using Urxvt "keysym" resource. For example, this shortcut (in my  `.Xresources`) does *previous-word* :

`*keysym.Control-h: \033[1;5D`

I didn't find a complete (working) list of sequences like this `1;5D`. I know a few others (Home, End...) but need some others (kill next word, kill last word, cancel last action...). The quest for this list is [not](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/83211/urxvt-map-esc-key-to-key-sequence) [new](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/116243/what-does-a-bash-sequence-033999d-mean-and-where-is-it-explained), but the answers aren't what they seem to be (not working, maybe not the `\033[` type ?). I spent hours on Google, Wikipedia, manual pages (urxvt, readline, ascii, xterm, bash...), it looks like some kind of cruel initiation.

Where can I find this reference ?

Comment: Did you ever find the answer? I'm looking for the same information.

I'm starting to suspect there are no sequences for things like "kill-word". These have to be manually defined in inputrc as readline commands.

If true, this sucks because readline can't handle semicolons...

Comment: @sicklybeans Sorry no, I played a little with inputrc then moved on...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's at least a list of the function keys and some Ctrl combinations: https://jscape.kayako.com/knowledgebase/article/View/5/7/sending-ctrla-ctrlh-f1-f12-and-other-function-keys-to-telnet-server

Here's a more complete list in one of the suckless tool's source code: http://git.suckless.org/sites/commit/db1cf4df877e9083fadd67e6f16f1a5552effe99.html

And here's an actual explanation of how some of this works, especially modifier keys http://www.leonerd.org.uk/hacks/fixterms/